# How to put number of correct and wrong answers into a single column on excel chart

Tags: excel, charts

I want to put the number of correct and wrong answers into a single column on the chart. I want all the correct answers(x) for question 1 are to be shown in green and all the wrong answers(y) in red. I have 338 papers. By looking at the chart one should be able to understand within these 338, 138 gave a wrong answers and there are 200 correct answers for question 1. So the column indicating question one should have 2 colors. Red for 138 wrong answers and Green for 200 correct answers.

**Update; Got the idea of it from the answer. Below is my example data now. Thanks again.** 
[image]

Comment: Are you effectively looking for a tutorial for how to create a stacked chart on excel? If so, then your question is off topic here. If you have tried to create the chart but have problems getting some things to work, then it would be a better question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jerry When I try to do it, each student gets a different color for their answers. I tried various "=Countif" but seem not able to do it. Am I using the wrong formula for that? If you can at least tell me which formula word I should use, I can figure out the rest.

Comment: I don't think you need any formula, well I'm assuming how you data looks like but I have no idea how it looks like, so I can't really say for sure. If it's something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ABbo.png), then it's not hard.

Comment: @Jerry do you see the below data? q1, q2 correct, false? I first wanted to enter correct and false for each student. Then, I wanted this data to interact directly with the chart. Like if it is correct I put a "x" if it is false I put a "y". However I could not do that. Below data gave me the idea, just sum up everything like that, and put that info into the chart. That was easy. However to count correct and false answer, I definitely needed =Countif which I am using now. If there is a way  that can directly interact with the "x" and "y" of each student I would be more than happy to learn.

Comment: You could make use of a pivot table, which is there precisely for that purpose. I just spun up a simple example and took a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pxx2.png). Then from that pivot table, you can insert a pivot chart which will turn out the same way as the graph in my previous comment after you work on it slightly for the colours and data labels.

Comment: @Jerry That will be really useful. I forgot about how to use excel completely as it had nothing to do with my job for many years. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Jerry, you will benefit from a short tutorial on how to create stacked bar chart. Like [this](https://www.smartsheet.com/stacked-bar-chart-graph) one for example.

Since your data is very small I'll demonstrate how to do this quick and easy:

- First you need your data set up correct, like so:

[image]

- Second you need to select the range of cells `A1` to `C9` and choose stacked bar chart under charts (also shown in link above).
- This will create your stacked bar chart

[image]

- Now click on a blue bar so it highlights that series and change its color to green:

[image]

- Then click right on the vertical axis and under options choose for max and unit `338`, see below screenshot (in Dutch, but you'll get the idea)

[image]

- Click the full chart and add a vertical chart title and change its title (again, Dutch but you'll get it)

[image]

- Final product:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I could do it totally. Now, This gave me another idea. I cannot explain well but if I cannot, I will be asking the community's help again.